# .env variables not working outside root file

Tags: node.js, express, dotenv

I have cretaed two .env variables
PORT=4000
NODE_ENV=DEVELOPMENT

When I use it outside root file(index.js) it doesnot load but i work completely fine if i remove if statement.

```js
module.exports = (err, req, res, next) => {
    err.statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'DEVELOPMENT') {
        console.log(err);

        res.status(err.statusCode).json({
            success: false,
            error: err,
            errMessage: err.message,
            stack: err.stack
        })
    }
}
```

Any solution

Comment: is that the full code of your file?

Comment: no but i cannot use process.env.PATH or any command outside root file

Comment: did you load your the your env file using require('dotenv').config() on that file?